# How to input a character 'j' after mapping "jj" to <esc> in vimperator?

Tags: firefox, vimperator

After using this code `:imap jj <esc>`, I can't input a single character 'j' in insert mode.
How to solve it ?

browser : firefox 47
plugin : vimperator 3.15

Answer (score 0):

```
:inoremap jj <esc>
```

should do the trick

Comment: Please add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Comment: @GilZ In fact I'm not exactly sure lol. Cuz this worked for me. My guess would be inoremap will not wait on the following command, instead it will output the first j immediately. I don't want to mislead the OP if im not 100% sure. Just saying its gonna work